# How to align a "column" of spans to the right?

Tags: html, css

I can't use divs.  All I can use is spans.  Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6a01v9a/1/

```html
<h4>How to align first "column" of spans to the right?:</h4>
<span style="float: left; width: 100px">Title1:</span><span>456415446</span>
<br/>
<span style="float: left; width: 100px">Long Title2:</span><span>16546446</span>

<br/><br/><hr>

<h4>Example (UI only.  Code is not right):</h4>    
<span style="float: left; width: 64px; padding-left: 36px">Title1:</span><span>456415446</span>
<br/>   
<span style="float: left; width: 100px">Long Title2:</span><span>16546446</span>
```

How can I align the first "column" of spans to the right regardless of size of text?

Updated:
Thanks guys!  Such a simple issue.  I was stuck on float and missed out text-align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `text-align` to `right`, with some `padding-right` value.

```html
<h4>How to align first "column" of spans to the right?</h4>
<span style="float: left; width: 100px; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">Title1:</span><span>456415446</span>
<br/>
<span style="float: left; width: 100px; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">Long Title2:</span><span>16546446</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a `text-align:right` with a equal width on every `span`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add text-align: right.

This look right to you?

```
<pre>
http://jsfiddle.net/3sfjojty/
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can add one more `<span>` to wrap the whole thing, then consider the following:

```html
<span style="display: block; width: 100%; text-align: right;">
<span>Title1:</span><span>456415446</span>
<br/>
<span>Long Title2:</span><span>16546446</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give 'text-align:right' for the span, for better result give a class for 1st span.

```
<span style="col1">Title1:</span><span>456415446</span>
```

and you can style it like.

```
span.col1{float: left; width: 64px; text-align:right;}
```